# How to create multi container pod from without yaml config of pod or deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

Trying to figure out how do I create multicontainer pod from terminal with kubectl without yaml config of any resource 
tried `kubectl run --image=redis --image=nginx` but second --image just overrides the first one .. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in a single `kubectl` command, but you could do it in two: using a `kubectl run` command followed by a `kubectl patch` command:

```
kubectl run mypod --image redis && kubectl patch deploy mypod --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"containers": [{"name": "patch-demo", "image": "nginx"}]}}}}'
```

Comment: exactly what searching for ... Cheers @ericstaples

Answer (score 0):

kubectl run is for running 1 or more instances of **a** **container image** on your cluster

see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands

Go with yaml config file

Comment: This creates two pods. The question asks for a multicontainer pod.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below steps

create patch-demo.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: patch-demo
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
----

deploy patch-demo.yaml

create patch-containers.yaml as below
---
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis
---
patch the above yaml to include redis container

kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch "$(cat patch-containers.yaml)"
```

Comment: got it right but I was trying to create the resource from kubectl without yaml config files @p-ekambaram